# Cbor package is failing

Tags: node.js, npm

We have installed nodejs version to 10.16.3. We are getting some error on cbor package while deploying.
can you please help on this?

```
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:38    | The cbor package REQUIRES Node.js v10.18 or higher.   |
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:38    | You are currently running Node.js v10.16.3            |
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:38    | Please upgrade node, or pin cbor to version 5.2.x:    |
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:38    | `npm install --save cbor@5.2`                         |
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:38    +-------------------------------------------------------+

error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR! errno 1
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR! cbor@7.0.5 preinstall: `node .checkVersion`
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR! Exit status 1
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR! 
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR! Failed at the cbor@7.0.5 preinstall script.
error   01-Jul-2021 10:42:39    npm ERR!
```

This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

Answer (score 0):

The error logs are saying you need to move to higher version of `Node.js` to run this package. If you can't update the node version, you can use the nvm package else update the global node and npm.

If you are on Linux based OS try installing [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm/blob/master/README.md) which helps you to maintain multiple versions of `node`, for the windows based OS try [nvm-windows](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). It will not break the current projects which are dependent on this version.

Comment: Hi Apoorva,

We have one nodejs application with cbor 5.0.2. and we have one deployment application(bamboo) with nodejs..Recently we have upgraded  node version in bamboo to 10.16.3.. after that we are facing this issue.. After upgraded we deployed some changes last week. that time it was smooth. But when we deploy some changes now, suddenly this is happening(new change is just small code change)

can you tell me why it is happening  suddenly??

and if we upgrade the version , will it affect our application which is running on cbor 5.0.2?

Comment: If you check the error logs, it says `Please upgrade node, or pin cbor to version 5.2.x:`.  It is happening because of version mismatch, not sure it should break the whole app, but any dependency of `cbor` needs higher version it might break.

Comment: But we haven't upgraded/installed cbor separately. we just upgraded nodejs. Then cbor correct version also would installed automatically right. i mean it should install correct version right?

Comment: When you update node, it also updates the peer dependency which in turn might have updated the `cbor` package and the new installation demands a min version of node greater that 10.18.X